# Huawei push and SDK statistics issues

Tags: android, sdk, push, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Why access Huawei Push and SDK statistics report `" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.huawei.agconnect.core.provider.AGConnectInitializeProvider: java.security.InvalidParameterException: url is null "`?

Access mode:

```
implementation'com.huawei.hms:push:4.0.3.300' 

implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.0.301'
```

Comment: Share your java class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have integrated the Huawei Analytics kit and Push services. The analysis kit requires developers to select a data storage location. The related information is stored in the agconnect-services.json file. After the analysis kit function is enabled and the storage location is configured, download the JSON file again and integrate it to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Pls re-download the agconnect-servies.json file from the AGC console, then add it to your Android project.  because when you turn on the analytics kit function, the console will generate some new parameters in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to download the json of the agconnect-services and then move it inside the proyect carpet

Answer (score 0):

Most services do require one to specify a "default data processing location":
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/agc-data-storage-location